# BDD python behave runner

Tags: python-behave

At the moment I am running feature files either individually or using the terminal and using the command behave.

Is there a runner class I can find somewhere that will run all the features one after the other that I can configure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behave [already](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/docs/behave.rst) include [configurable](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/docs/behave.rst#configuration-files) runner into it.

Comment: Yes thanks but how does this run feature files. I already have the behave.ini, but how to configure it to run features?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [django-behave](https://github.com/django-behave/django-behave/) if you're using Django.